# Showing python unittest results in an accessible way

Tags: python, unit-testing

Essentially I'd like to be able to show the results of the unittests in a way non-technical people can access, e.g. a google sheet or something.

Is there a way to do this?

I have looked at TestRunner but not sure it does what I want.

I'm quite new to python and unittesting, so ideally I'd like it to be as simple as possible.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I suggest you find Brian Okken on Twitter and ask him.